# Java - array initialization with user specified size

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, array-initialization

I'm trying to create a program that receives the size of the array from user input and then accepts that amount of integers and then displays all the prime numbers among them. So for instance if the user enters that they want the array to be of size 5, then it should allow the user to enter 5 integers. However I'm stuck and it's giving me an error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrayprime {

public static void main (String[] Args)
{   
    boolean isprime = true;
    int i=0;
    int[] Array = new int[i];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter how large you want the array to be: ");
    i = keyboard.nextInt();

    for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
        Array[j] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    int k = 2;
    while (k <= Math.sqrt(Array[i]))
    {
        if (Array[i] % k == 0)
        {
            isprime = false;
            break;
        }
        k++;
    }
    if (isprime==true)
    {
        System.out.println(Array[i] + "is prime.");
    }
}
}
```

The error I've been getting is:

```
     "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at arrayprime.main(arrayprime.java:18)"
```

Comment: Ask the size first, and then create your array.

Answer (score 1):

Read your code:

```
int i=0;
int[] Array = new int[i]; //--> Array = new int[0]

...
while (k <= Math.sqrt(Array[i])) //"i" can be any number, but Array has size 0.
```

Move

```
i = keyboard.nextInt();
```

before the initialization of `Array`

Comment: Thanks that worked. But now I have another problem with this line - " int k = 2;
  while (k <= Math.sqrt(Array[i]))
  {. It's I'm not sure if I initialized that loop correctly.

Comment: @user2444400 _Which_ problem?

Comment: "
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at arrayprime.main(arrayprime.java:28)" And line 28 s that line with the initialization of the squareroot of the value in Array[i]

Comment: @user2444400 I see it. Java indexes are zero-based. So, if you have an array of size `5`, then `4` is the last available index. When you ask for `Math.sqrt(Array[i])` you are calling `Math.sqrt(Array[5])`, which doesn't exist: the last available index is `Array[4]`.

Comment: Ah ok it works great now that I set it to Array[i-1] in the loop. Thanks!

Comment: @user2444400 Suggestion: pick a java book and learn the basics. You can't code without them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your whole array when you are check for all the primes.

You should also initialize the array once you know how big you want it to be.

Lastly you need to account for numbers being less than 2 not being prime.

If you make these changes you should get something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrayprime {

public static void main (String[] Args)

{   
    boolean isprime = true;
    int i=0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter how large you want the array to be: ");
    i = keyboard.nextInt();
    int[] Array = new int[i];
    keyboard.nextLine();

    for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
        Array[j] = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

    }


    for (i = 0; i < Array.length; i++){
        int k = 2;
        if (Array[i] < 2){
            isprime = false; 
        }
                else{
            while (k <= Math.sqrt(Array[i]))
            {
                if (Array[i] % k == 0)
                {
                    isprime = false;
                    break;
                }
                k++;
            }
                }
        if (isprime)
        {
           System.out.println(Array[i] + " is prime.");
        }
        isprime = true;
    }


}
}
```

Which I believe works as to what you wanted.

Edit: I have had problems with Scanner.nextInt() before because of it leaving an empty space in the queue that gets picked up at the next Scanner.next___(), so i tend to avoid using it. However that is just personal option.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Here

```
int i=0;
int[] Array = new int[i];
```

you reserve storage for your array but `i` is still `0` at this moment.

So the array has a length of `0` and you
fail when you try adding elements to it.